# Need help on Java Program to calculate weight on planets

Tags: java

I am doing this program that calculates the weight by planet. I have to display a chart with 3 columns, planet names, Gravity values, and Weight. I am trying to do this program, but I always get the output of the Gravity Values as NaN and 0.0 for all Weight Values.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
public class WeightOnPlanetsV1
{
    public static double[] getGravity( ) throws IOException {
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("output.txt"));
        double[] Gravity = new double[8];
        double[] abc = new double[8];
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            abc[i] = fileScanner.nextDouble();
            Gravity[i] = abc[i] / 9.79211720754188E34;
        }
        fileScanner.close();
        return Gravity;
    }
    public static double[] calcWeight(){
        double earthWeight =100.0;
        double[] Weight = new double[8];
        double[] Gravity = new double[8];
        double[] mass = new double[8];
        for(int a = 0; a < 8; a++){
            mass[a] = (earthWeight * 433.59237) / Gravity[a];
            Weight[a] = mass[a] * Gravity[a];
    }
    return Weight;
}
public static void PrintResults( ) throws IOException{
    double[] Gravity = calcWeight();
    double[] Weight = new double[8];
    String[] planets = new String[8];
    planets[0] = "Mercury";
    planets[1] = "Venus";
    planets[2] = "Earth";
    planets[3] = "Mars";
    planets[4] = "Jupiter";
    planets[5] = "Saturn";
    planets[6] = "Uranus";
    planets[7] = "Neptune";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
        double weightonEarth = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("        My weight on the Planets        ");
        System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("%10s     %9s     %8s", "Planet",    "Gravity",     "Weight on planet(lbs)");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------   -------");
         for(int y = 0; y < 8 ; y++)
           {

               System.out.printf("%-11s", planets[y]);     
               System.out.printf("%13.2f", Gravity[y]); 
               System.out.printf("%20.2f\n",Weight[y]);
        }

}
}
```

Here are my output values

```
3.681794655084276E34
8.863175348783772E34
9.79211720754188E34
3.6956542096917174E34
2.476892445877445E35
6.032365515665391E31
8.863553576713065E34
1.11374098023869E35
```

I will really appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you debug your code, i.e. step through it with a debugger?

Comment: Btw, I don't see you call `getGravity()` anywhere, so maybe you mean ` double[] Gravity = getGravity();` in `calcWeight()` (note that creating an empty double  array will initialize the values to 0 and thus `weight = mass * gravity` will return 0 if `gravity` is 0.

Comment: Your output values do not appear to represent the possible output from the code you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gravity values are being calculated from this:

```
double[] Gravity = calcWeight();
```

Inside `calcWeight()`, you return a `double[] Weight` array which is calculated from:

```
Weight[a] = mass[a] * Gravity[a];
```

As @Thomas correctly pointed out, you never actually assign any values to `Gravity[]` because `getGravity()` is never called.  So the denominator of each `Weight` value will be zero, i.e. this is a divide by zero which I believe is the cause of the `NaN` values for `Gravity` which you are seeing.

Inside `PrintResults()`, the `Weight[]` array is never defined, hence they are all zero.

**How to fix your code:**

You can try using the following:

```
public static double[] getGravity() throws IOException {
    // same as before
}

// pass the already-computed gravity array to this method
public static double[] calcWeight(double[] gravity) {
    double earthWeight = 100.0;
    double[] weight = new double[8];
    double[] mass = new double[8];

    for (int a=0; a < 8; a++) {
        mass[a] = (earthWeight * 433.59237) / gravity[a];
        weight[a] = mass[a] * gravity[a];
    }
    return weight;
}

public static void PrintResults() throws IOException {
    double[] Gravity = getGravity();
    double[] Weight = calcWeight();

    // keep the rest as is
}
```

Comment: ok, but can you please explain how I can fix this, and get the output with the  right Gravity and Weight values

Comment: I need an output like this

Comment: http://learn.flvs.net/webdav/educator_apcsa_v14/module07/rtfmod07/07.04_AssignmentInstructions.pdf

Comment: I updated my answer.  This is probably as close as I can get without pasting your code into IntelliJ and testing end-to-end; I hope it is enough for you.

Comment: ok, now its telling me that method calcWeight in class WeightonPlanetsV1 cannot be applied to the given types

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `getGravity` anywhere. Instead you are assigning weights to gravity like this:

```
double[] Gravity = calcWeight();
```

Fix it by replacing the line with this:

```
double[] Gravity = getGravity();
```